# Reset color property of SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, colors, skspritenode, uicolor

What's the default `color` value of SKSpriteNode?

It's not mentioned in the Apple docs, and comparing the default property to `nil` or `UIColor.white` returns false, suggesting it's neither of these.

The goal is to reset a node's color to the default value after running a `SKAction.colorize` animation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `colorBlendFactor` to 0 causes the `color` property to get ignored.

> The value must be a number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive. The default
>   value (0.0) indicates the color property is ignored and that the
>   texture’s values should be used unmodified. For values greater than
>   0.0, the texture is blended with the color before being drawn to the scene.

This option solves the problem, but doesn't answer the question of the default `color` value.

Hopefully someone else posts a definitive answer to the question.